# How to drop out of a programme in java?

Tags: java, eclipse, case, do-while, void

I have made a main menu in my code. When the user types q I want the code to stop running. Instead it just presents the menu again, what code should i use to stop this. If you press any other letter it works.Thank you

```
    import java.util.Random;

    public class Aaa {
        AQAConsole2016 console = new AQAConsole2016();
        Random random = new Random();
        int boardSize;
        boolean moveIsValid;

        char [][] board;
        int move;
        char choice;
        String playerName="Human";
        String player2="Computer";
        public Aaa() {




            boardSize = 6;

            do {
                displayMenu();
                choice = getMenuChoice(playerName);
                switch (choice) {
                case 'p' : playGame(playerName, boardSize);
                break;
                case 'e' : playerName = getPlayersName();
                break;
                case 'c' : boardSize = changeBoardSize();
                break;
                case 'm' : Multiplayer( boardSize,playerName,player2);
                break;
                case 'r' :readBoard(board,boardSize);
                break;
                case 'q' : quit();


                }
            }while (choice!='p'||choice!='e'||choice!='c'||choice!='m'||choice!='r'||choice!='q');
        }
        void quit(){


    }
```

Comment: You don't need a `quit` method, just spend more thoughts into your `while` loop and why `while (choice!='p'||choice!='e'||choice!='c'||choice!='m'||choice!='r'||choice!='q')` will always be true.

Comment: @Debugging the while-loop is endless. Take a look [boolean algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra) to understand the mistake you made in the condition of the while-loop. Simply stepping out of the loop would be enough to quit.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too localized. Questions here are supposed to help other people as well, not only the asker of the question

Answer (score 0):

this is not going to work just because

`case 'q' : quit();` is just a call to a method, i.e. when the method is done it will return to the do while...

you need instead to add some boolean condition that can be modified if the option menu is selected...

doing something like

```
while (!exit);
```

where exit is a boolean variable...

and you can in the void method:

```
void quit(){
    //Do your stuff before exit
    exit=true;
}
```